# Azure Text to Speech: can't get async methods working when using C API

Tags: c, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am experimenting with [Azure Text-To-Speech API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/text-to-speech/).In the SDK I found C API which I prefer to their C++ API as it heavily uses smart pointers and other STL elements I don't use in my code. Microsoft doesn't provide any docs for the C API. I was trying to write in C based on their C++ "Getting started" example, which goes like this:

```
auto config = SpeechConfig::FromSubscription("MyAPIKEY", "MyRegion");
auto audioConfig = AudioConfig::FromWavFileOutput("file.wav");
auto synthesizer = SpeechSynthesizer::FromConfig(config, audioConfig);
auto result = synthesizer->SpeakTextAsync("A simple test to write to a file.").get();
```

Works fine.

In C it looks like this:

```
SPXSPEECHCONFIGHANDLE scHandle;
speech_config_from_subscription(&scHandle, "MyAPIKEY", "MyRegion");
assert(speech_config_is_handle_valid(scHandle));
SPXAUDIOCONFIGHANDLE audioConfig;
audio_config_create_audio_output_from_wav_file_name(&audioConfig, "file.wav");
assert(audio_config_is_handle_valid(audioConfig));
SPXSYNTHHANDLE synthesizerHandle;
synthesizer_create_speech_synthesizer_from_config(&synthesizerHandle, scHandle, audioConfig);
assert(synthesizer_handle_is_valid(synthesizerHandle));
synthesizer_completed_set_callback(synthesizerHandle, &OnSoundGenerated, NULL);

const char* text = "A simple test to write to a file.";

SPXASYNCHANDLE asyncHandle;
synthesizer_speak_text_async(synthesizerHandle, text, strlen(text), &asyncHandle);
assert(synthesizer_async_handle_is_valid(asyncHandle));
```

Nothing happens, no file is written, no callback is triggered(tried different), and the process doesn't terminate event that the main() function returned.

I also tried to wait on the asyncHandle, but same thing.

```
SPXRESULTHANDLE res;
synthesizer_speak_async_wait_for(asyncHandle, 1000, &res);
```

Replacing async call with the regular one works fine.

```
SPXRESULTHANDLE res;
synthesizer_speak_text(synthesizerHandle, text, strlen(text), &res);
```

I would like to understand, if the async part of the API is not supposed to be used at the moment, or I am rather doing something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

`async` is working. The result of `synthesizer_start_speaking_text_async` will be returned when the synthesis starts with no audio synthesize at that moment. So even if you wait for the async handle then exit, the SDK cannot execute synthesis. You need to wait more time for the `SynthesisCompleted` event, or call `synthesizer_speak_text_async` instead of `synthesizer_start_speaking_text_async`.

Comment: I am sorry,I put the wrong async method in my code example.I actually was using synthesizer_speak_text_async ,but I also tried synthesizer_start_speaking_text_async . None of those work. My input text is just severa words. It never returns. The process hangs on the main() exit. Calling waiting functions didn't work either.